# Verificar se subdomínio existe com Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dns

Quero verificar se um subdomínio presente em um site existe.
Tentei utilizar `urllib.request.urlopen()` mas ele retornar o status code como 200 mesmo que não exista.
Isto ocorre porque meu provedor retorna uma página indicando que o DNS não existe. Como posso verificar sem que o provedor "atrapalhe"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função 'gethostbyname' da biblioteca 'socket' pra fazer um DNS Lookup. Exemplo:

```
import socket

try:
    ip = socket.gethostbyname('blah.google.com')
except socket.gaierror:
    print('Domínio não existe')
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema. ^-^